# Adding Lists Elements to 'Mega List'

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list somewhere called `majorPowers` which contain these two lists:

```
axis=["germany","italy","japan"]
allies=["russia","uk","us"]
```

I'd like to insert each of the elements of these lists, into a new *mega-list*. I'm currently doing this:

```
>>> temp = []
>>> temp = [ww2.append(t) for t in majorPowers]
>>>ww2
[['germany','italy','japan'],['russia','uk','us']]
```

How do I adjust this to not use the `temp` and to insert the individual elements into `ww2` instead of the lists themselves(`axis` and `allied`).

Also, would the new *mega-list* itself be classed as a comprehensive list, or the process of making it?

EDIT:

Please note I do not want to do:

```
for a in list1:
    for b in a:
        c.append(b)
```

@S.Lott. I understand your point. However I'm trying to learn some of the tricks in Python, instead of the standard way I'd usually do things. This is just to open my mind to Python a little more!

Comment: What's wrong with your "I do not want to do" solution?  (1) it works.  (2) it's short and perfectly clear.  What's wrong with it?

Comment: python list.extend mean 'for for b in a: c.append(b)'

Comment: I just wanted to note that your list comprehension using append could have been written ww2 = [axis,allies] to produce that result. There are some nice solutions below but they don't mention list flattening, which is what you are doing. If you google for "Python list flatten" then you should come upon some discussions of interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is good that you ask this question, because it is **bad form** to misuse list
comprehensions like that. The code you show uses `append`, not to generate the
elements of `temp`, but because of its side effects. **Avoid side effects in list
comprehensions**!

So, there are a couple of things you can do. First, you can use
[`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#chain):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*mayorPowers))
['germany', 'italy', 'japan', 'russia', 'uk', 'us']
```

Instead of passing the elements of `mayorPowers` as individual arguments to `chain`, you can also use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(mayorPowers))
['germany', 'italy', 'japan', 'russia', 'uk', 'us']
```

Or you can use [`extend`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

```
>>> ww2 = []
>>> for mp in mayorPowers:
...     ww2.extend(mp)
...
>>> ww2
['germany', 'italy', 'japan', 'russia', 'uk', 'us']
```

Or [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#sum) (I like this one most, I suppose):

```
>>> sum(mayorPowers, [])
['germany', 'italy', 'japan', 'russia', 'uk', 'us']
```

Or, to be a little crazy (uses [`functools.reduce`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functools.html#reduce) and [`operator.add`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/operator.html#operator.add)),

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import add
>>> reduce(add, mayorPowers)
['germany', 'italy', 'japan', 'russia', 'uk', 'us']
```

Comment: I don't think you need to import reduce - I think `reduce` and `map` are builtins (at least from 2.5)

Comment: @thrope: In 2.x yes, but not in 3.x. (`reduce` was often abused. And as you can see, in this example too, it is not the preferred method.)

Comment: You always provide a thorough, well written answer, Stephan202. Much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain
ww2 = list(chain.from_iterable(majorPower))
```

Comment: Alternatively, since there is a finite number of mayor powers, `list(chain(*mayorPowers))`.

Comment: what's the problem with using itertools?

Comment: also from_iterable was introduced in 2.6

Comment: when something can be done in simpler way and works on all version, i will choose simple and shorter version

Comment: but I don't see why my answer is wrong - it doesn't deserve downvoting

Answer (score 0):

try extend

```
for t in majorPowers: ww2.extend(t)
```

or

```
sum(majorPowers,[])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use reduce:

```
from operator import add
ww2 = reduce(add, majorPowers)
```